# Rails 4 embed HTML in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, link-to

I have the following `href` code

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
```

**Rails Code**

```
<%= link_to "<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>", event_expenses_accept_path(:id => event_expense.id), :method => :post, :class => "accept btn btn-sm btn-success", remote: true %>
```

**Tried**

```
<%= link_to (raw("<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>"), event_expenses_accept_path(:id => event_expense.id), :method => :post, :class => "accept btn btn-sm btn-success", remote: true)  %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [blocks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to):

```
<%= link_to("#", class: "add_fields btn btn-success") do %>
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<% end %>
```

Which will generate:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-success" href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</a>
```

Also, this will also work:

```
<%= link_to (raw("<i class=\"fa fa-check\"></i>")), event_expenses_accept_path(:id => event_expense.id), :method => :post, :class => "accept btn btn-sm btn-success", remote: true  %>
```

Generating:

```
<a class="accept btn btn-sm btn-success" data-method="post" data-remote="true" href="your_path" rel="nofollow">
    <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the HTML as block, try this

```
<%= link_to event_expenses_accept_path(:id => event_expense.id), :method => :post, :class => "accept btn btn-sm btn-success", remote: true do %>
  <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will also work:

```
<%= link_to(content_tag('i', '', class: 'fa fa-check'), "#", class: "btn btn-sm btn-success") %>
```